# How to divide list items in 2 columns, fill the first before the second, without setting ul height?

Tags: html, css

I have a list with 2 columns. I will add elements to it on demand and I would like to fill the first column and when it is full, the second.

The problem is that the height of the list will be determined by the height of its parent (user could resize), so I don't want to set the list height.

Here is one example setting the list height:

https://jsfiddle.net/zwfv26hp/

HTML:

```
<div>
<ul>
<li>word</li><li>word</li><li>word</li><li>word</li><li>word</li><li>word</li><li>word</li>
<li>word</li><li>word</li><li>word</li><li>word</li><li>word</li><li>word</li><li>word</li>
<li>word</li><li>word</li><li>word</li><li>word</li><li>word</li><li>word</li><li>word</li>
<li>word</li><li>word</li><li>word</li><li>word</li><li>word</li><li>word</li><li>word</li>
<li>word</li><li>word</li><li>word</li><li>word</li><li>word</li><li>word</li><li>wordEnd</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
  column-fill: auto;
  column-count: 2;
  max-height: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
```

**Clarifying my question**: the parent in this case is a div that has the screen height minus the page header (another div) height. So it varies according to the user resolution.

Comment: Does it need to adjust dynamically?

Comment: Without any kind of fixed height, how are the items supposed to know where to break?

Comment: Initially, fill the first and then second? how much data do you want to fill in the first column?

Comment: @Venky I want to fill as much as I can according to the available space, which derives from the size of the user's screen resolution.

Comment: @Michael_B see my edits :)

Comment: something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/zwfv26hp/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the parent element is resizable, than it has height. What you need to do is just set the height of the list to 100%. Your problem is your solution:

> the height of the list will be determined by the height of its parent

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
}
html, body {
     height: 100%;
 }
 header {
     height: 100px;
     background: none #eee;
 }
 ul {
     margin: 0;
     column-fill: auto;
     column-count: 2;
     -moz-column-fill: auto;
     -moz-column-count: 2;
     height: calc(100vh - 100px);
 }
```

```html
<header>
    <h1>Header</h1>
</header>
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[Updated Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/zwfv26hp/3/).

**EDIT**: Updated to last requirements.

Comment: It's a nice answer, but you are setting the height of the parent and I don't know the size of the parent in advance. Think of the parent as the body, where the screen size of the user will define its height.

Comment: There you are, with header fixed height.

Comment: Perfect! I didn't know about "calc", awesome!